# Installing VB 6 and oracle 8i

Tags: oracle

We are bank having VB 6 on the front end and oracle 8i as the back end and we were using this software in windows XP service pack 2 for all these years and now the microsoft has withdrawn the XP from market we are not in position to buy new system for using.

So I would like to know if we can use our VB 6 and oracle 8i in the linux platform and if so please guide me in which version of linux is suitable.

Thank you. Looking for your really ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

No. Visual Basic is a Microsoft product that does not work with Linux/Ubuntu. VB does also not properly work using a tool like wine (let alone that a bank should be working with wine).

If you want to become independent of Microsoft and that software you use was built in-house someone will need to re-code all your software from Visual Basic to something like Python or Perl for it to work on Linux/Ubuntu.

The Oracle 8i database is still supported by Oracle? Oracle 12c works on Ubuntu but that is a newer system and probably also requires you to upgrade.

Besides security related problems: if that Windows XP is not connected to the internet you can keep using it while creating an alternative. It is going to take time and money to transform software from Windows XP to Ubuntu or even to another Windows. You should have started creating alternatives the day Microsoft announced it was going to stop support for XP.